# Check if div with certain class name exists AS NEIGHBOR, side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

With jQuery or plain JS

For example:

```
<div class="mydivclass">Some Text1</div>
<div class="am I beside mydivclass ???">Some Text2</div>
```

Comment: use the css `+` operator

Comment: `$(".mydivclass+.am_I_beside_mydivclass").length`

Comment: not quite @CarstenLøvboAndersen ... `document.querySelector('div.mydivclass+div.am.I.beside.mydivclass')` (or `$` if you **must** use jQuery) - note: title asks for a div with certain class name, not any element :p

Answer (score 3):

Use the "+" operator.

Here is an example, as you can see only the second is green as it's directly after the first div.

```css
.first, .second, .third {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
.first + .second {
  background-color: green;
}
.first + .third {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but the example was referring to a class and not a script to determine if it was a neighbor.

Comment: It might be needed for a functionality, for instance, if a neighbour has a job-completed class, then do nothing, else start some job. Your answer is a CSS design answer, while the question was about frontend programming.

Answer (score 1):

A neighbor can be before or after the element in question:

```
<div class="mydivclass">Some Text1</div>
<div class="am-I-beside-mydivclass">Some Text2</div>
```

### Simple Javascript

```
Node.prototype.getClasses = function() {
    return this.className ? this.className.split(" ") : "";
};

Node.prototype.hasClass = function(c) {
    return this.getClasses().indexOf(c) >= 0;
};

function isNeighbour(element, cn) {
    var siblings = element.parentNode.children;
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(element.parentNode.children, element);
    if (index === -1) return false;
    return (index >= 0) && 
            (((index > 0) && (siblings[index - 1].hasClass(cn))) || 
            ((index < siblings.length - 1) && (siblings[index + 1].hasClass(cn)))
           )
}
```

`getClasses` returns the classes of any `Node`, `hasClass` checks whether a `Node` has a `class` and `isNeighbour` checks whether a `class` name matches the previous or next sibling of the element.

### jQuery

```
function isNeighbour(element, cn) {
    return (element.prev().hasClass(cn) || element.next().hasClass(cn));
}
```

This code is very easy to understand, but it has jQuery as a dependency.